# Monk ACFs, substitutions, or variants that trade in the default AC bonus?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monk, alternate-class-feature

In an amusing (to me anyway) reversal of [my previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50844/4563), I have a character who is taking a single level of monk for the purposes of bonus feats. This character has Wisdom 8 and wears (light) armor anyway, so the Wisdom to AC bonus is worthless.

So: is there any alternate class feature, variant class, or substitution level that trades Wisdom to AC for anything at all? To be clear, I’m not looking to replace *Wisdom* to AC (i.e. get something else to AC), I’m looking to replace the monk “AC bonus” class feature with *anything at all* (which *could be* but doesn’t *have to be* something-other-than-Wisdom to AC).

Literally anything (that’s gained at level 1) is more valuable than Wisdom to AC for this character, so there is a low bar, but in my research nothing touches it.

**Note this character doesn’t have feats to burn on this,** so stuff like the Ascetic Mage feat isn’t helpful. On the other hand, the armor is rather minor and can be discarded; right now I have armor because it’s better than my Wisdom in terms of AC bonus, but the character has extremely high Dexterity and so uses gnomish twist cloth (+1 AC, no max Dex armor from *Races of Stone*) which can easily be removed if a variant also requires you to be unarmored. Items are also possibilities, though I doubt any would help. Changing levels to a non-monk is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to have a null default answer:

### No, there are no such variants. Every monk has Wis-to-AC unless they spend feats to change it.

This statement is based on [the Alternative Class Features handbook](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=8732.0), the most up-to-date version of that guide to my knowledge, as well as Chet Eretz’s base class index, which occasionally has things the ACF handbook does not.

None of the variant classes, subsitution levels, or alternate class features touch the Wisdom to AC feature. Only one touches the AC Bonus feature at all, but Durable Monk replaces only the +1 bonus every five levels (and then doesn’t grant anything until 8th).

Comment: This answer is fine for my purposes, I just wanted to see if it was wrong, i.e. someone could find a counter-example.

Comment: To be honest I don't believe that having "default" answer accepted would invite people to look for other answers.

Comment: @Mołot This question is almost a month old, and has gotten nothing but answers that had to be deleted because they weren’t actually answers. I’m literally accepting it *so that people will let this question die.* The answer is no. Fine, that’s what I wanted to know. If someone comes along later and says “wait, actually!” then awesome, but I really don’t want any more “no, but *something that doesn’t actually answer the question and isn’t helpful,*” answers.