# Does a low Wis Swordsage have an AC penalty?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

Swordsages get:

> Starting at 2nd level, you can add your Wisdom modifier as a bonus to your armor class

I have a warblade who has an 8 WIS (-1 mod), and was thinking of taking a two level dip into swordsage.

Comment: The wording on the Swordsage ability is really important for this question.  I'm away from my ToB copy, and online sources for the wording bring me to a different conclusion than your question's version of the wording.  Basically, it comes down to if the wording is "add their Wisdom bonus" or "add their Wisdom modifier as a bonus".

Comment: @godskook From the book: "Starting at 2nd level, you can add your Wisdom modifier as a bonus to your armor class" then it lists the armor and encumbrance limitations.

Comment: If you are taking a one level dip, are you even getting that ability? (Question is still fine, just curious about this)

Comment: @firedraco hahaha oops. Edited. Gotta take one before you take two.

Comment: Since this question is about an ability called “AC Bonus” that adds one’s Wisdom to AC, and this is useless to your character as described, [this question about possible alternatives to the monk’s version](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50986/4563) might be of interest to you—and might even be useful if the answer was anything but “there aren’t any.”

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It says you **can** add your Wisdom modifier as a bonus. It does not say you have to, or that it just happens whether you want it to or not. It is your choice. If your modifier is negative, you presumably would not choose to add it.

Comment: Was about to post this answer myself; instead I'll +1 yours. I think this answer is even more important than the one by godskook.  I don't remember the rules defining such a difference between bonus and modifier; perhaps my memory is just lapsing, but I don't think it was there, and as a DM I would not accept godskook's rationale. I would, however, accept "I choose not to apply my wisdom to my dodging."

Comment: @Aaron godskook's answer has a link to the game's distinction between *bonus* and *modifier* in its quotation, but I, too, think KRyan's point is a very strong one: the special ability's *can* implies that it's an option that need not be exercised, no matter how the remainder of that special ability's actually worded.

Comment: "No, no I need to not this dude, I use my -1 modifier on these swings." "Why don't you just... not swing?" "Well my magic sword gains 3 hp when I attack. I don't want to kill the dude until I'm back to full hp..."

Comment: @corsiKa That is funny but also true and a good example. Spell resistance is another good example, and if I recall correctly rulebooks specifically talk about willfully lowering your personal spell resistance when you might want to be affected by something, either a beneficial spell or even a negative spell for whatever odd reason you have.

Answer (score 6):

## Bonuses are not Modifiers

> [A positive modifier is called a bonus, and a negative modifier is called a penalty.](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm)

A bonus is *ALWAYS* positive. If you don't have have a Wisdom bonus, you can't add it to your AC, but you also can't add your Wis modifier, or Wis penalty.  So where the rules say "add your ability bonus", you only do that if your modifier is positive, by definition.

## However, the text is ambiguous

The text says you can add your Wisdom *modifier* as a *bonus*, which is confusing phrasing, in my opinion, because they're switching terms non-meaningfully.  It ~should~ be the same term for both, either as modifier or bonus.

## It still says bonus, though

To me, the argument's there that this class feature should always be non-negative.  Still, I'd say talk to your DM.

## Work around

Carrying an animated shield negates the class feature entirely, bonus or penalty, and the animated shield doesn't interfere with your attack routines.  So for 9kgp, you can bypass the need to discuss the ruling at all.

Comment: I don't remember the rules defining such a difference between bonus and modifier; perhaps my memory is just lapsing, but I don't think it was there. The text that you quote and link also does not imply the difference you extrapolate from it. "A positive modifier is a bonus and a negative modifier is a penalty" is not the same thing as "If any modifier that you apply using the wording 'bonus' would actually be negative then do not apply it." And if I were DM, I might apply the bonus as a penalty in certain situations; it would depend on the circumstances.

Comment: @Aaron’s memory is largely correct; the rules usually call out the distinction between bonus and modifier explicitly when it’s relevant, e.g. “Wisdom bonus, if any,” and similar.

Comment: @Aaron, the quoted text *IS* a definition.

Comment: Maaan, I wish my level 2 character had 9kg to spend on magic items...

Comment: @ThunderGuppy, OP's character is already a Warblade, so at a *MINIMUM*, we're talking level 3 before there's a potential conflict on this, likely a few levels later.

Comment: @godskook I was merely illustrating that a (possibly relatively) expensive magic item might be a bit of a silly solution.  XD  ...if nothing else, there are various +2 wis magic items available for less than half that price that would counter the wisdom penalty in ANY situation.

Comment: @godskook It is a definition, yes, but not a definition that says what you then take from it. The text you quote&link does not seem to imply everything you say after it. Saying "a bonus is a positive thing and a penalty is a negative thing" does not mean "if the rules put you into a situation where you apply a bonus and the modifier is negative, then do not apply it." That may have been the intention of the original authors, perhaps, or perhaps not; I do not know. As a DM, I would do what makes sense for the situation, which could go either way.

Comment: @godskook Please note that I am not saying you are reading it wrong, just that we are reading it differently. I am, however, saying that you cannot insist that the authors must have meant "a modifier labeled as bonus is ignored if negative." They may have intended that, but if so they did a poor job of wording it. A DM might well side with you. I wouldn't, but others might. I did _not_ -1 your answer, for the record.

Comment: @Aaron, I'm not arguing intent, I'm arguing RAW.  A penalty is, by definition, not a bonus, and if the text says "you add your Wisdom Bonus", then the text is explicitly stating that you add your bonus, not your modifier.

Comment: @godskook fwiw it's a level 7 warblade. I was looking to start dipping at level 9 to take the full compliment of concentration saves.

Comment: Join me in chat?  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63826/room-for-godskook-and-francisjohn

Comment: @godskook That still does not address my concern. I am specifically stating that "A positive modifier is called a bonus, and a negative modifier is called a penalty." (and the rest of the text in your link) does not mean "When you go to apply a bonus, don't do so if the modifier is negative (and therefore would be a penalty)" nor "When you go to apply a penalty, don't do so if the modifier is positive (and therefore would be a bonus)" The text you quote and link does not say this, so your "I'm arguing RAW" sides with my statement. In fact, this may be why so many rules add can/may/if-any/etc..

Comment: Example: I take a new feat which is about pacifist magical defense in a supplemental book which states "Add your weapon's magic bonus to your armor class instead of to your attack rolls." Assume the background on the feat makes it not a conscious thing, let's say it's supernatural, so you have no choice in the matter (cannot suppress it). Seems simple enough. However, say my fighter got duped into wielding a cursed -1 sword last session and he uses it because it also penalizes him some other way if he doesn't use it. That -1 is not a bonus but should still be applied.

Comment: In OP's case, the action is voluntary. Players should always be able to just say "I choose not to do that" for any voluntary action. I can always say "I choose not to apply my +3 dex bonus to AC when that guy hits me. Either my armor will stop it, or it won't." Imagine tough guy standing firm and still to prove himself. But a player can never say "I choose to try and dodge that attack, so I'll apply +3 dex, but I choose to not have my armor block it. Either I dodge it or die." Can't do; armor is not a voluntary action. No matter the rules, you can say "I'm going to ignore wisdom while I fight"

Comment: @Aaron, by your wording, no, a -1 Sword's modifier would not apply, per RAW.  That's my argument/position, and we've seemingly exhausted any worthwhile conversation about such.  As far as the voluntariness of this particular case, I actually agree with KRyan, but that's been tangential to the discussion you and I have been having.

Comment: @godskook "would not apply, per RAW. That's my argument/position." Except that you haven't actually argued. I have said why the text you quoted does not apply. That leaves you with no RAW rules backing up your statements. To exhaust a conversation means you are progressing it. You just keep saying that it works the way you claim in your answer without suggesting why, beyond your initial quote which does not back up your ruling.

Comment: @Aaron, I have argued as such, you just disagree, and I don't find your disagreement convincing.   We've past the point of appropriate comment dialog, and if you want to continue this in chat, I'm only willing if you'll, at the very least, acknowledge that yes, I have argued as such(regardless of the quality of that argument).  Otherwise, I don't think we can have a constructive dialog.